# Change date format in Parameter (RDLC Report)

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, formatdatetime

How can I change the date format when time and date is in one parameter?

```
Parameters!DateTimeFrom.Value
```

I want to change it in `MM-dd-yyyy`.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this,

```
=Format(CDate(Parameters!DateTimeFrom.Value),"MM-dd-yyyy")
```

OR if you want to show time also- `MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss` , then you should try below,

```
=Format(CDate(Parameters!DateTimeFrom.Value),"MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

Comment: in question you mentioned that, you want to change it 'MM-dd-yyyy` - that's why I have give you this line of code, so you want it with time?

Comment: It's fine now. Thanks :)